# convert variable of ternary operator to if-else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operator-keyword, ternary

```
x = (year % 100 === 0) ? (year % 400 === 0) : (year % 4 === 0);  
alert(x);
```

hi guys, how can I convert this variable x to if-else statement returning the variable in true or false result?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
year = 2010;

if(year % 100 === 0)
    x = (year % 400 === 0);
else
    x = (year % 4 === 0);  
alert(x);
```

```
if(year % 100 === 0)
    x = (year % 400 === 0);
else
    x = (year % 4 === 0);  
alert(x);
```

Comment: @AhQuan check the snippet

Comment: thanks mate! but if I type like this (with {}) then it won't show false                                                                       if(year % 100 === 0){
    x = (year % 400 === 0);
}
else
{
    x = (year % 4 === 0);  
    alert(x);
}

Comment: any idea why? sorry I can't paste code in comment section

Comment: e.g. year 1700, without {} it will return false, but wont otherwise

Comment: you need to put the alert outside the {}